# Can we bound from above sub-solutions of Volterra integral equations? (Nonlinear Gronwall's Lemma)

Tags: real-analysis, integral-equations

**Gronwall's lemma** says the following. Assume that $v\in C^0([t_0, T])$ is a nonnegative function. If $u \in C^0([t_0, T])$ satisfies the integral inequality

$$u(t) \le c + \int_{t_0}^t u(s)v(s)\, ds,\qquad t \in [t_0, T]$$

where $c\in\mathbb{R}$, then

$$u(t) \le c \exp\left(\int_{t_0}^t v(s)\, ds\right), \qquad t \in [t_0, T].$$

In other words, *sub-solutions* of the linear integral equation

$$w(t)=c+ \int_{t_0}^t v(s)w(s)\, ds, \qquad t \in [t_0, T]$$

are dominated by solutions of the same equation, *provided that the coefficient $v$ is nonnegative*.

> **Question** What can we say about the general Volterra equation 
>   $$\tag{1}\ w(t) = c + \int_0^t F(s, w(s))\, ds,\qquad t \in [0, T]?$$
>   Under what conditions on $F$ is a sub-solution of (1) dominated by a solution?

Comment: I am not sure taht your equation (1) is the general Volterra equation. Your equation is equivalent to the initial value problem for the differential equation $w'=F(t,w)$, $w(\tau)=c$. The Volterra equation of the first kind is the linear integral equation $w(t)=\int_a^b k(s,t)w(s)ds$, where $k(s,t)$ is the kernel. Of course, there is a second kind.

Comment: @Juliàn: Unfortunately I'm not an expert of those things. I'm used to call *Fredholm integral equation* what you have called *Volterra equation of the first kind* and *Volterra equation* (without specifying any kind) the one I refer to in the question above. My only reference on this is Debnath-Mikusinski's book on Hilbert spaces.

Comment: @dissonance: In your question title I think you mean "bound above" not "estimate."

Comment: @anon: You found a flaw in my English. What is the difference between those terms in current language? I guess that "estimate" is reserved to bounds in absolute value, am I right?

Comment: @dissonance: It'd be easier to explain if we knew your native language. :) The word "estimate" means to approximate, or try to get as close as possible, to some value - it has nothing to do with bounding variables. Sometimes we might speak of bounding the error of our estimates - seeing just how close we know we can get to something.

Comment: @anon: *Native language* should not be very difficult to determine, starting from dissonance's user page... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sufficient condition is that every function $F(s,\cdot)$ is nondecreasing. That is:

> For every $s$ in $[\tau,T]$, $v\le v'$ implies $F(s,v)\le F(s,v')$.

In full generality, this condition is probably also necessary.

Comment: I'm a bit busy right now and so I will think about your answer as soon as possible. In all cases, thank you very much for your interest.

Comment: This is just to let you know of the following answer. Looks like the @name functionality is disabled outside comments.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer but a (long) comment to Did's answer. In a nutshell: I think that we need to add a Lipschitz condition on $F$ (assumption 2 below). Did probably assumed it implicitly.

Here's a possible way to argue. **Assume that**:

1. for all $s\in[0, T]$, one has that $x\le y\Rightarrow F(s, x)\le F(s, y)$;
2. there exists a constant $L>0$ such that $\lvert F(s, x)-F(s, y)|\le L\lvert x-y\rvert$.$^{[1]}$

Let

$$u(t)\le c+\int_0^tF(s, u(s))\, ds,\qquad w(t)=c+\int_0^tF(s, w(s))\, ds.$$

**We claim that** 
$$\tag{1}u(t)\le w(t).$$ 
*Proof*. Consider the set 
$$
X=\left\{t\in [0, T]\ :\ u(t)-w(t)>0\right\}.$$
Assume by contradiction that $X$ is nonempty and set 
$$
t_0=\inf X.$$
Since $u$ is a subsolution we have that $t_0>0$. By assumption 1 we have that 
$$
F(s, u(s))-F(s, w(s))\le 0\qquad \forall s\in[0, t_0].
$$
So for $t\in X$ we have by assumption 2
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
0<u(t)-w(t)&\le \int_0^tF(s, u(s))-F(s, w(s))\,ds \\
&\le \int_{t_0}^t F(s, u(s))-F(s, w(s)\, ds \\
&\le L\int_{t_0}^tu(s)-w(s)\, ds,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
and Gronwall's inequality gives the contradiction $0<u(t)-w(t)\le 0$. $\square$

I don't know if condition 2 can be weakened, but surely it cannot be dropped altogether. One must have at least a uniqueness result for the integral equation, and condition 2 gives such a result (that's the standard Picard's existence and uniqueness theorem).

For example, consider this problem:

$$w(t)=\int_0^t \big(w(s)\big)^{1/3}\, ds.$$

We know that there exist more than one solution to this equation, and of course every solution is a subsolution. If our claim were true in this case we would have for a pair of distinct solutions $w_1, w_2$ the inequalities $w_1(t) \le w_2(t)$ and $w_2(t)\le w_1(t)$, that is, $w_1(t)=w_2(t)$, a contradiction.

An open question remains, and it it necessity of the monotonicity condition on $F(s, \cdot)$. This is intuitively reasonable, but should be proved.

---

$^{[1]}$ It is enough to assume those conditions for almost all values of $s$.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMO. As you demonstrate, the Lipschitz condition is crucial.

Comment: @MartinR: thanks a lot, it is always a pleasure to receive feedback, as you know. While I am happy about your comment, I am not going to unaccept an answer after 12 years (!) to accept mine, it doesn't feel right! :-) But thanks again for the feedback.