# General case of Gronwall's inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

In my ODE class, the statement below is said to be true.

> $F(t,x)<G(t,x) \quad \forall (t,x)\in[a,b]\times\mathbb{R}$
>
> $f'(t)=F(t,f(t))\quad g'(t)=G(t,g(t))\quad f(a)=g(a)=c$
>
> $\Rightarrow f(t)\leq g(t)\quad \forall t\in [a,b] $

I have seen [another vision](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43707/can-we-bound-from-above-sub-solutions-of-volterra-integral-equations-nonlinear) with stronger assumptions. But I wonder if it's sufficient with only the pairwise inequality. (For simplicity, let's assume $F,G$ is continuous and Lipschitz continuous in x, but not always monotonic.)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/43707/8157 HTH

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: That  Q&A that is already referenced in the question :) – Actually I am not sure if the problem here is related to Gronwall's inequality at all. There are some similarities, but this here seems to be an “easier” case of differential inequalities.

Comment: :-D :-D :-D the fact that I didn't click on the link just got outed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the difference $h(t) = g(t) - f(t)$. Then
$$
 h(a) = c - c = 0, \quad h'(a) = G(a, c) - F(a, c) > 0
$$
so that $h$ is strictly positive on an interval $(0, \delta]$.

Now assume that $h(t_1) <0$ for some $t_1 \in (0, b]$. Then $h$ must be zero somewhere between $\delta$ and $t_1$ and we can define
$$
 t_0 = \max \{ t \in [0, t_1] \mid h(t) = 0 \} \, .
$$
Then $h(t_0) = 0$ and $h(t) \le 0$ for all $t \in [t_0, t_1]$, so that $h'(t_0) \le 0$. On the other hand, $f(t_0) = g(t_0) =: d$, and 
$$
 h'(t_0) = G(t_0, d)) - F(t_0, d) > 0
$$
gives a contradiction.