# Integral inequality implies majorization by solution of ODE

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:[0, \infty)\to [0, \infty)$ be non-decreasing (and not necessarily differentiable nor continuous) and satisfy $$f(t)\leq f(0)+C\int_{0}^{t}f(s)^{2}ds,$$ where $C>0$. Is it true then that $$f(t)\leq g(t)\quad \text{for all}~t<t_{*},$$ where $t_{*}>0$ and $g$ is a differentiable function on the interval $[0,t_*)$ such that $$g'(t)=Cg(t)^{2}\quad\forall\,0<t<t_*, \quad g(0)=f(0)?$$

Obviously if we would have equality in the above integral inequality and differentiability of $f$, we would have $f=g$, but is it still true that $f\leq g$ under these weaker assumptions?

My idea is to discretize it (by the monotonicity of $f$), so that we have $$f_{n}\leq f_{0}+C\sum_{k=1}^{n}{f^{2}_{k}}$$ and by the assumption on $g$, $$g_{n}= g_{0}+C\sum_{k=1}^{n}{g^{2}_{k}}, \quad g_{0}=f_{0},$$ and show that $f_{k}\leq g_{k}$ for all $1\leq k\leq n$ but the inductive step does not seem to be working.

Comment: $g^2(t)$ usually means the composition $g(g(t))$, $\sin^2(t)$ etc. are grandfathered-in. For all others use $g(t)^2$.

Comment: I can’t find a complete proof yet. One idea would be to build approximate functions $f_\epsilon$ that satisfy the same inequality for all $t$ but $f_\epsilon(0)< f(0)$. Then it should be easier to prove that $f_\epsilon< g$ by a continuity (bootstrap) argument, and then $f\leq g$ by approximation. I suspect one approximation that should work is $f_\epsilon(t)=g(g^{-1}(f(t))-\epsilon)$, but one would need to find a direct proof that the inequalty still holds. Different approximations might work as well. I would be curious to see a clean, elementary proof.

Comment: In any case, the result is definitely true. It’s just a bit annoying to prove. Of course you need to assume that the integral above makes sense, but if $f$ is monotone it is measurable (and also locally bounded), so there is no problem at all.

Comment: [This old question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/43707/8157) looks like it is strictly related.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: It surely is. One difference is that $f$ (which is $u$ in your question) is not assumed to be continuous, so that one has to argue a bit more carefully. Even Grönwall's inequality (as least as I know it) assumes continuous functions.

Comment: @MartinR: that's certainly right. I just went through your answer. If $f$ were continuous, as in the standard formulation of Grönwall, there would be no need to consider $h^+$ and all the technical complications that follow. Considering $|h|$ would be enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes the conclusion is true. One can show that
$$
 h(t) = f(t) - g(t)
$$
is zero or negative on every interval $[0, t_1] \subset [0, t_*)$.

We have
$$
f(t)\leq f(0)+C\int_{0}^{t}f(s)^{2} \, ds
$$
and
$$
g(t) = f(0)+C\int_{0}^{t}g(s)^{2} \, ds
$$
and therefore
$$
 h(t) \le C \int_0^t (f(s)^2-g(s)^2) \, ds = C \int_0^t h(s)(f(s)+g(s)) \, ds \, .
$$
Now let $h^+(t) = \max(h(t), 0)$ be the positive part of $h$, and $M$ be an upper bound for $f+g$ on $[0, t_1]$. Such a bound exists because $f$ is non-decreasing and $g$ is continuous. Then
$$
 h(s)(f(s)+g(s)) \le h^+(s)(f(s)+g(s)) \le M h^+(s)
$$
so that
$$
 h(t) \le CM \int_0^t h^+(s)\, ds 
$$
and therefore
$$
 h^+(t) \le CM \int_0^t h^+(s)\, ds \, .
$$
It is now a standard procedure to show that this implies $h^+(t) \le 0$ for all $t \in [0, t_1]$: $H(t) = \int_0^t h^+(s)\, ds $ is absolutely continuous with
$$
 H'(t) = h^+(t) \le CM H(t)
$$
almost everywhere, so that $\phi(t) = e^{-MCt} H(t)$ is differentiable almost everywhere with $\phi'(t) \le 0$. Since $\phi(0) = H(0) = 0$ it follows that $\phi$ and consequently $H$ are $\le 0$ on $[0, t_1]$, and finally
$$
 h(t) \le CM H(t) \le 0 \, .
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Why we need that $f$ is non-decreasing to get that upper bound?

Comment: If $f$ is increasing then $f(t) \le f(t_1)$ gives an upper bound for $f$ on $[0, t_1]$. Note that $f$ is not assumed to be continuous.

Comment: Ok thanks. I forgot that $f$ was not assumed to be continuous...

Answer (score 0):

The result is definitely **NOT** true.

First of all if
$$g'(t)=Cg(t)^2~~,~~g(0)=f(0)$$
Then you can easily find
$$g(t)=\frac{f(0)}{1-f(0)Ct}$$
Because $f(0)\geq 0 ~,~C>0$, there **always** exists some $t_*$ such that $g(t)<0~\forall t>t_*$, you can of course see that
$$t_*=\frac{1}{f(0)C}$$
Therefore, if we are assuming $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ from the start, then, $\forall t>t_*$, we would have $f(t)\color{red}{\boldsymbol >}g(t)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Maybe, I had to be more precise in the answer, that I want majorization only for $t<t_{*}$ for some $t_{*}>0$.

Comment: @Shaq155 Oh I see, okay.

Comment: @Shaq155 I see the problem with how the question was formulated (I overlooked it in my previous comments), but I think it's too arbitrary to extend $g$ to be negative for $t>t^*$. Such a function $g$ does not satisfy the equation for all times. And most importantly, the result is certainly true for all $0<t<t^*$ (that is, as long as $g$ is defined).

Comment: @lorenzo-pompili Yes, this is how it is meant.

Comment: @Shaq155 , sorry, I wanted to reply to K.defaoite